# iPage MySql Create Or Replace Trigger

Tags: mysql, replace, triggers

I'm having issues creating a trigger in MySql Database on iPage hosting.

Here is the code:

```
delimiter $$ 


CREATE TRIGGER update_rfp_estado BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_ac_rfp 
 FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),NEW.fecini) < 0 THEN
            SET NEW.estado = 1;
        ELSEIF DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),NEW.fecfin) > 0 THEN
            SET NEW.estado = 3;
        ELSEIF DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),NEW.fecini) >= 0 THEN
            SET NEW.estado = 2;
        END IF;

END;$$
delimiter;
```

This trigger checks the current date with the new date and change the NEW.estado depending on the conditionals.

The error i'm getting is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `update_rfp_estado` BEFORE UPDATE ON `wp_ac_rfp` ' at line 1
```

What could be the error? Thank you in advance

Comment: `END;$$` should be `END $$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error creating MySQL Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554315/error-creating-mysql-trigger)